# How Can I launch my own Wizard from visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-addins

I have form(Wizard) that after some steps  it generate some code.All works and I am happy.

In a nutshell  I would like to launch this form from visual studio ,very much like a template but its not a template ,

How can I launch my already written generation process from Visual Studio? Can I just reference it as dll and launch the form? 
What is the best way to do this?

Should I Create an Addin? or any links or suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An AddIn sounds like a good solution. If you create an addin you have access to the projects and files inside the current solution and can add your generated files to the project.